# MySQL Counting Group

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

So I have a table structure like this...

```
SAMPLES
| id | session | category | status | localfile |
```

I'm trying to get a list of matching localfiles including:

All sessions with 3 files with status = "complete" in category "x" "y" and "z"

I DON'T WANT ANY results for sessions that DON'T have ALL 3 CATEGORIES.

So results should be something like:

```
1, 100, x, complete, c:\...
2, 100, y, complete, c:\...
3, 100, z, complete, c:\...
34, 106, x, complete, c:\...
35, 106, y, complete, c:\...
36, 106, z, complete, c:\...
```

NOT:

```
1, 100, x, complete, c:\...
2, 100, y, complete, c:\...
34, 106, x, complete, c:\...
35, 106, y, complete, c:\...
36, 106, z, complete, c:\...
```

It doesn't seem like it should be that complicated but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find what sessions have

- `('x','y','z')`
- have status = `complete`
- and have all 3
- the `DISTINCT` is optional in case a session can have repeated category.

.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Samples
 WHERE session IN (SELECT session
                   FROM Samples
                   WHERE category IN ('x','y','z')
                     AND status = 'complete'
                   GROUP BY session
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category) = 3)
  -- optional if there are other categories
  AND category IN ('x','y','z')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had something similar but couldn't get all the way there.

Comment: I don't think there is a way you can know who downvote the question. And isn't worthy spend time guessing or holding a grudge about it.